# If-else statements made my program stop immediately -- Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm just going to post what I've got so far in a program that is supposed to do the following:
- Calculate BAC (blood alcohol content) based on inputs given by the user and determine, with the various inputs, whether or not they would get a DUI (be over the limit based on inputs given).
So here's my code:
import java.util.*;

```
public class Proj2_Mazzone
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String gender;
        int D, W, H, age;
        double ratio, limit, alcAbsorbed, alcMetabolized, BAC;
```

...

```
//BAC is calculated here, based on given input
//Make 4 diff scenarios using && with if statements...
//So f21, fnot21, m21, mnot21
System.out.print("Enter M if you're a male, or F if you're a female: ");
    gender = scan.nextLine();
    //males over 21
    if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("m") && age > 21){
        ratio = .73;
        limit = .08;
        alcAbsorbed = (3.701 * D) / (W * ratio);
        alcMetabolized = .015 * H;
        BAC = alcAbsorbed - alcMetabolized;
        if(BAC >= limit){
            System.out.println("You're over the limit!");
            System.out.println("Your BAC is " + BAC + "!");
            }
            else if(BAC <= limit){
                System.out.println("You're good...for now.");
                System.out.println("Your BAC is " + BAC + ".");
                }
        }
    //males under 21
    if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("m") && age < 21){
        ratio = .73;
        limit = .02;
        alcAbsorbed = (3.701 * D) / (W * ratio);
        alcMetabolized = .015 * H;
        BAC = alcAbsorbed - alcMetabolized;
        if(BAC >= limit){
            System.out.println("You're over the limit!");
            System.out.println("Your BAC is " + BAC + "!");
            }
            else if(BAC <= limit){
                System.out.println("You're good...for now.");
                System.out.println("Your BAC is " + BAC + ".");
                }
        }

    //females over 21
    if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("f") && age > 21){
        ratio = .66;
        limit = .08;
        alcAbsorbed = (3.701 * D) / (W * ratio);
        alcMetabolized = .015 * H;
        BAC = alcAbsorbed - alcMetabolized;
        if(BAC >= limit){
            System.out.println("You're over the limit!");
            System.out.println("Your BAC is " + BAC + "!");
            }
            else if(BAC <= limit){
                System.out.println("You're good...for now.");
                System.out.println("Your BAC is " + BAC + ".");
                }
        }

    //females under 21
    if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("f") && age < 21){
        ratio = .66;
        limit = .02;
        alcAbsorbed = (3.701 * D) / (W * ratio);
        alcMetabolized = .015 * H;
        BAC = alcAbsorbed - alcMetabolized;
        if(BAC >= limit){
            System.out.println("You're over the limit!");
            System.out.println("Your BAC is " + BAC + "!");
            }
            else if(BAC <= limit){
                System.out.println("You're good...for now.");
                System.out.println("Your BAC is " + BAC + ".");
                }
        }
```

...
It may not be the best way to do it, but any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Checking the code right now. In the meantime, you need to fix the fact that this doesn't work for a person at age 21.

Comment: Ah...that is true. I was thinking...should I have used a for loop for each scenario? Like a for loop for f21, fnot21, m21, mnot21 and then do the same statements inside?

Comment: When do you initialize your `age` variable?

Comment: Vincent - I initialized it with a scan.nextInt right above where I asked if the user is male or female.

Comment: What do you mean with "stop"? Does it never exit? Which row is "stopping"?

Comment: @vidstige - I mean as soon as I press 'm' or 'f' the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem in the else if statements is that one of them may not trigger. Instead of doing an `if else if` statement in the `if(BAC<=limit)`, do something like:

```
    if (BAC >= limit) {
        System.out.println("You're over the limit!");
        System.out.println("Your BAC is " + BAC + "!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You're good...for now.");
        System.out.println("Your BAC is " + BAC + ".");
    }
```

Also, do you ever read the age in you program?

Comment: Age is initiated before all this through a scan.nextInt. Also, I tried doing it that way but the limit wasn't initiated yet, so it wouldn't let me... I tried making the limit an if else statement under age and it didn't work.

Comment: _Then initiate the limit!_ There's no point to this program if there is no limit. Try my solution and see if it works.

Comment: It might be because it's late and I'm exhausted, but I couldn't figure out how to initiate the limit and try to call it in the if-then statement below.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing same code again and again you should create one common function. That will take 2 arguments that is ratio and limit.
Apart from this all other calculations are common for all age limits and male or female.

Do your calculation in that function and simply print it
it will shorten your code and will make it more readable and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

There's a logic problem: 21 year old females fall through. Your main ifs are:

```
if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("f") && age > 21){
    ...
}

if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("f") && age < 21){
    ....
}
```

If the age is exactly 21, neither block will be entered.

Comment: I fixed it and it still closes as soon as I press m or f.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to refactor this code after you've found the problem to reduce duplication. Also try to avoid if-statements that may cause no code to be run, instead use an if-else statement - You always want to print *something*, otherwise it feels as the program just stops.

Perhaps something like this

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    // Scan variables etc

    // calculate ratio
    double ratio = -1;
    if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("m"))
    {
        ratio = .73;        
    }
    if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
    {
        ratio = .66;
    }

    // calculate limit
    double limit = -1
    if (age > 21)
        limit = .08;
    limit = .02;

    // calculate blood alcohol level
    alcAbsorbed = (3.701 * D) / (W * ratio);
    alcMetabolized = .015 * H;
    double bloodAlcoholLevel = alcAbsorbed - alcMetabolized;

    if(bloodAlcoholLevel >= limit)
    {
        System.out.println("You're over the limit!");
        System.out.println("Your BAC is " + BAC + "!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("You're good...for now.");
        System.out.println("Your BAC is " + BAC + ".");
    }
}
```

This way your code can be much shorter and easier to read, not to mention change. :-)

Comment: I won't be able to use any of that, I think. We haven't learned about 'return, private, throw, illegal argument exception'

Comment: @Mazzone I've updated the answers so that the functions are inlined, and thus does not use keywords 'private', 'static', nor 'return'. No teacher sees anything wrong in a student learning too much! You could also research the 'return' keyword. It's a very important one. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the fact that your conditions are wrong for a women who is 21 year old! She's excluded from all the cases.

Also your code is hard to debug because it's hard to read.
Consider the following refactoring where I created methods to determine the values.
I went very far for a simple code like that but it's to show you that you should *never* copy/paste code. When you repeat code, it means that you can put it in a method that will be called several times with the right arguments.

```
public class StackOverflow {
    // TODO define the real values!
    private static final int D = 0, W = 0, H = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get the input
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter M if you're a male, or F if you're a female: ");
        String gender = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your age: ");
        int age = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());

        // Get the good values
        double ratio = getRatio(gender);
        double bac = getBAC(ratio);
        double limit = getLimit(age);

        // Print the result
        if (bac <= limit) {
            System.out.println("You're good...for now.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You're over the limit!");
        }
        System.out.println("Your BAC is " + bac + "!");
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the ratio according to the gender.
     */
    private static double getRatio(String gender) {
        if ("m".equalsIgnoreCase(gender)) {
            return .73;
        } else if ("f".equalsIgnoreCase(gender)) {
            return .66;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown gender: " + gender);
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the BAC according to the ratio.
     */
    private static double getBAC(double ratio) {
        double alcAbsorbed = (3.701 * D) / (W * ratio);
        double alcMetabolized = .015 * H;
        return alcAbsorbed - alcMetabolized;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the limit according to the age.
     */
    private static double getLimit(int age) {
        if (age < 21) {
            return .02;
        } else {
            return .08;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see my answer. But perhaps its just a case of great minds think alike? :-)

Comment: Haha! I didn't see your post, I was writing mine. As you say, great minds think alike ;)

Comment: Well...while I really, really appreciate you putting in the work, that code includes a lot of stuff that we haven't learned in class yet and this is for a project that I'm trying to do early. So I'm going to let you know in a week or so towards the actual due date if I end up using return and private stuff. Thanks a bunch!